# ASP.NET Core MVC Ajax call not passing parameters to api controller method

Tags: c#, ajax, api, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

I'm trying to call API controller method using ajax and passing some parameters. The api method is getting called but values are coming as null in controller method.

Using same ajax call, another controller (not api controller) having same method receives parameter values and returns results but i'm stuck with passing values to api controller method. Kindly help

```
 $(document).ready(function ()
                {
                    $("#DropDownName").change(function ()
                    {
                        $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            dataType: "text",
                            url: "@(Url.Action("SampleAction", "XYZController"))",
                            data: {
                                "param1": $("#DropDownName :selected").val(),
                                "param2": $("#input2").val(),
                                "param3": $("#input3").val()
                            },

                            success: function (response) {

                            document.getElementById("result").textContent = "Result: " + response;
                        },


                        });
                    });　
                });
```

API Controller Method

```
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class XYZController : ControllerBase
    {
        [ActionName("SampleAction")]
        [HttpPost]
        public decimal SampleAction(string dropdownselectedvalue,decimal input2, int input3)
        {
         //code here - This method is getting called but getting null parameter values
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your ajax like below:

```
data: {
        "dropdownselectedvalue":$("#DropDownName :selected").val(),
        "input2": $("#input2").val(),
        "input3": $("#input3").val(),
},
```

Be sure add `FromForm` in your backend code:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class XYZController : ControllerBase
{
    [ActionName("SampleAction")]
    [HttpPost]
    public decimal SampleAction([FromForm]string dropdownselectedvalue,
        [FromForm] decimal input2, [FromForm] int input3)
    {
        return input2;
        //code here - This method is getting called but getting null parameter values
    }
}
```

Comment: [FromForm] made it work. First part was right in actual code. I have put some dummy names for parameters here.